# Linux cut command with -f1

Tags: cut

What is the meaning of the following command:

```
cut -d" " -f1
```

I found out what cut `-d" "` means: removing spaces, right?

but what means this `-f1`?

Comment: Try `man cut`...

Comment: Note that `-d" "` _does not_ mean removing spaces.

Comment: ... but defining fields separated by a certain character. To give another example, `-d\!` would look for `!` per line and from each `!` starting, `cut` would define a new field. Also note the important `-` which can be used for field names: `-f2-` will mean "from field #2 to end of line", which can be invaluable when amount of fields per line is expected to vary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`cut` cuts/splits lines on the delimeter (specified by `-d`) and then selects certain fields from those cut up lines. Which fields is specified by `-f` (counting starts at 1, not at 0)

If you would have a file `xyz` with contents:

```
1 2 3
4
5 6
```

then

```
cut -d' ' -f1 xyz
```

would give you:

```
1
4
5
```

(even if there is no space at all on the line with just the 4)

All of this and e.g. that `-s` suppresses lines that do not have the cut character can be found in the `man` page for cut (`man cut`)